# Count items in comma separated list in single cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Is there a formula that will count the number of items in a cell, each separated by a comma?

For example:

CELL A1 = "Dell, Apple, Samsung, Acer"

Formula would return 4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With data in **A1**, in another cell:

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1
```

**NOTE:**

The formula will **not** handle strings like:

```
,,,,,,,A,,,B,,,,
```

Comment: Simple and superb

Comment: Notice if you have a tailing `,` in your cells then you may want to remove that extra `+1` at the end of the formula.

Comment: Besides the trailing comma, it also counts an empty cell as 1. This fixes both, including trailing spaces after a trailing comma: =IF(ISBLANK(IF(RIGHT(TRIM(A1),1)=",",LEFT(TRIM(A1),LEN(TRIM(A1))-1),A1)),"0",LEN(TRIM(IF(RIGHT(TRIM(A1),1)=",",LEFT(TRIM(A1),LEN(TRIM(A1))-1),A1)))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(IF(RIGHT(TRIM(A1),1)=",",LEFT(TRIM(A1),LEN(TRIM(A1))-1),A1)),",",""))+1)

Comment: @Jacob I concur ; if you post an answer, I will up-vote it.

Comment: I can't since the question is protected.